# telegram plus messenger source code

Tags: telegram, messenger

I want to release one unofficial app using Telegram API that have tabbing 
so  found Telegram plus messenger in this address : 
( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.plus ) 
and its source in GitHub at : https://github.com/rafalense/Plus-Messenger
but it is source of old version (2.5.2.1)
how can find new version of plus messenger source code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of Plus Messenger sadly isn't up to date. Latest version is 3.8.1.2 (you can find it in the dev branch).

Comment: That's not update too

Answer (score 2):

The code was moved to the Gitlab:
https://gitlab.com/rafalense/plus-messenger